# How to delete a row in a section with Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I need to delete a row in a section but it deletes the row in upper section. Please help find problems of my codes. Also, please advise how to delete the section when deleting the row? There is one row in a section.

```
    var sectionTitles = [String]()
    var savedURLs = [[String]]()

    func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return savedURLs.count
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {
        return sectionTitles[section]
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {   
        return savedURLs[section].count
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
         let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("SavingCell")
        cell?.textLabel!.text = savedURLs[indexPath.section][indexPath.row]
        return cell!
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, commitEditingStyle editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {        
        if editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyle.Delete {
            savedURLs[indexPath.section].removeAtIndex(indexPath.row)
            NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(savedURLs, forKey: Key_SavedURLs)
            savingTableView.reloadData()
        }
    }
```

Comment: I don't see problems with your code. To me it seems like it should work as expected. Could you please attach some screenshots which illustrate the problem which you are facing?

Comment: Hi Andriy, thanks for your quick reply. That is amazing! I checked my app again, it is the problem of other codes in the app.  So codes here are fine. Can you advise any clue how to also delete the section when deleting the row? There is only one row in a section.

Comment: sure, will write an answer in 2-3 minutes :)

Comment: ok, Andriy, I figured out, thanks.

Comment: Is it this:       savedURLs.removeAtIndex(indexPath.section)

Comment: yes, I have posted the answer with exactly this suggestion :) although pay attention that for this to work savedURLs should be defined as [[String]] (2d array)

Comment: why didn't you put as Answer?

Comment: I did. Maybe you need to refresh the page

Comment: My original codes are just as what fatihyildizhan has edited, this website always has this problem when copy and paste codes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To delete empty sections modify your code to this:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, commitEditingStyle editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

    if editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyle.Delete {

        savedURLs[indexPath.section].removeAtIndex(indexPath.row)

        // now check if a section is empty and, if so, delete it

        if savedURLs[indexPath.section].count == 0 {
            savedURLs.removeAtIndex(indexPath.section)
        }

        NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(savedURLs, forKey: Key_SavedURLs)

        savingTableView.reloadData()
    }
}
```

although for this to work your `savedURLs` should be `[[String]]`

Comment: all done, everything ok. Moving forward now. Have a good day!

Comment: Is there a particular reason that you are using reloadData when there is a deleteSections function on UITableView? Smoothly animated transitions are so much more professional.

Comment: @GlennHowes sorry for spotting your comment only now. Sure, deleteRow is a much better way. The reason why I didn't include it in my original response is because it requires a bit more code and is not directly related to the original question (handling empty sections) :)

Answer (score 1):

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, commitEditingStyle editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

    if editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyle.Delete {
        savedURLs.removeAtIndex(indexPath.section)    
        NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(savedURLs, forKey: Key_SavedURLs)

        savingTableView.reloadData()
    }
}
```

try this.this should work..

Comment: fahad, thank you, too. Andriy answers first, so I picked his answer. Yours works, too.